# Expanding all arguments of a command before appending it to another macro

Tags: expansion

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{7}

\newcommand{\mysndc}[3]{#1 #2 #3}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{}

\newcommand{\mytrdc}[1]{\ltx@GlobalAppendToMacro{\mycommand}{%
\mysndc{\arabic{mycounter}}{#1}{\thepage}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
x

\mytrdc{8}

\newpage
\setcounter{mycounter}{4}

\mycommand
\end{document}
```

When `\mycommand` is called, it is `\mysndc{\arabic{mycounter}}{8}{\thepage}` resulting in `4 8 2`. What I would like it to be is `\mysndc{7}{8}{2}` resulting in `7 8 1`. To achieve this, the arguments of `\mysndc` must be expanded before `\mysndc` is appended to `\mycommand`. `\expandafter` should be useful, but diverse placements of it (also more than one `\expandafter`) did not yield the desired result, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\mytrdc}[1]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ltx@GlobalAppendToMacro{\mycommand\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mysndc\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\arabic{mycounter}\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter#1\expandafter}\expandafter{\thepage}}}
```

. Where must I place how many `\expandafter`s to expand the arguments of `\mysndc` before appending it to `\mycommand` and why exactly? I found numerous similar questions and answers to them here at tex.SE, but still was not able to get it right. If possible, I prefer a solution with `expandafter`s, so that I can learn from it, and without using e-TeX/etextools/etextoolbox/LaTeX3/...

Comment: Can you be sure that the arguments are all expandable? If so, does your macro itself need to be expandable? To what extent are we allowed to make assumptions about the input? Can we use e-TeX?

Comment: @JosephWright: `\arabic{mycounter}`, `8`, `\thepage` should all be expandable, but I would prefer an e-TeX-free solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to tackle this is probably to force expansion of everything using `\edef`, as that was we avoid needing to shuffle arguments. (`\mytrdc` is not expandable in any case, so we can use an assignment.) One possible approach using `\edef`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{7}

\newcommand{\mysndc}[3]{#1 #2 #3}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytrdc}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{%
    \endgroup
    \noexpand\ltx@GlobalAppendToMacro{\noexpand\mycommand}{%
    \noexpand\mysndc{\arabic{mycounter}}{#1}{\thepage}}}%
  \x}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
x

\mytrdc{8}

\newpage
\setcounter{mycounter}{4}

\show\mycommand
\end{document}
```

The idea is simple: create a temporary, `\edef`ed macro `\x` which contains the expanded material required plus the necessary 'set up', then execute it. Everything is done in a group so we don't mess up any other meaning of `\x`.

Comment: I'm taking it we don't have a full description of the expandability of the arguments beyond the fact that they are expandable. (Number of expansion steps required is not fixed.)

Comment: Instead of expanding _something_ you expand _everything_ but `\noexpand` those things that shall not be expanded? Clever!

Comment: @Stephen Yes: working on the basis that we don't have to use `\expandafter` as your overall aim involves an assignment anyway, I took the easiest approach for forcing expansion.

Answer (score 11):

You *could* do it with `\expandafter`, but it would be really long, as passing from `\arabic{mycounter}` to 7 requires four steps of expansion:

```
\arabic{mycounter}
\expandafter \@arabic \csname c@mycounter\endcsname
\@arabic \c@mycounter
\number \c@mycounter
7
```

Expanding `\thepage` requires one step more, because the first level expansion is `\arabic{page}`.

Let's see it in a simpler case. You have

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\dosomething{#1}}
```

where `\dosomething` is your “append” macro, where you want that `#1` is the “final” result after expansion of the argument. So, if you have

```
\def\foo{A}
```

you want that `\dosomething` is fed with `A`, rather than with `\foo`. This is easy:

```
\expandafter\mymacro\expandafter{\foo}
```

If instead you have

```
\def\foo{\baz}\def\baz{A}
```

you need to expand `\foo` twice:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mymacro
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\foo}
```

In general, if you want n expansions, you need 2<sup>n</sup>–1 `\expandafter` tokens. In the case of `\arabic{mycounter}` you'd need 15 before and after `\mymacro`. For `\thepage` they would be 31. But the affair is complicated by having three arguments!

So a different approach is needed. The simplest one is to use `\edef` or, in case your arguments can contain “dangerous” things such as `\textbf`, with `\protected@edef`; I'll do it slightly differently from Joseph's answer, just for fun.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{7}

\newcommand{\mysndc}[3]{#1 #2 #3}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytrdc}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\x{{\arabic{mycounter}}{#1}{\thepage}}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mycommand\expandafter
    {\expandafter\mysndc\x}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
x

\mytrdc{8}

\newpage
\setcounter{mycounter}{4}

\texttt{\meaning\mycommand}
\end{document}
```

The `\x` temporary macro will expand to `{7}{8}{1}` and it will disappear as soon as the chain of `\expandafter`'s is performed (the group will be ended after `\x` has been expanded.

Here's a different approach, with LaTeX3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\mysndc}[3]{#1 #2 #3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytrdc}{ m }
 {
  \stephen_mytrdc:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ }
 {
  \tl_use:N \g_stephen_list_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \g_stephen_list_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \stephen_mytrdc:n #1
 {
  \stephen_appto_mycommand:ffn { \arabic{mycounter} } { \thepage } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \stephen_appto_mycommand:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_stephen_list_tl { \mysndc { #1 } { #3 } { #2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \stephen_appto_mycommand:nnn { ff }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setcounter{mycounter}{7}

x

\mytrdc{8}

\newpage
\setcounter{mycounter}{4}
y

\mytrdc{42}

\expandafter\show\csname g_stephen_list_tl\endcsname
\end{document}
```

In a real document you'd use `\mycommand` instead of `\show`. The double inversion of the arguments is for efficiency. The output on the terminal will be

```
> \g_stephen_list_tl=macro:
->\mysndc {7}{8}{1}\mysndc {4}{42}{2}.
```